# Mover Google Maps cuando se mueva la posición del Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Tengo una aplicación para ubicar sitios (Fijos desde BD), ademas de eso muestra mi ubicación (Móvil), al momento de moverme mi ubicación se actualiza pero el mapa se mantiene igual, y mi problema es, que cuando mi posición se sale del mapa que se muestra, como puedo hacer que el mapa se vaya moviendo a medida que mi posición se mueve. Igual que lo hace la aplicación de google maps. Es una aplicación web pero que lo puse en webview para móvil.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando van cambiando las posiciones, lo que deberias usar es un CameraUpdate con la latitud y longitud de donde queres ir, por ejemplo

```
        //Guardamos las latitudes y longitudes donde queremos ir
        LatLng coordenadas = new LatLng(lat, lng); 
        //15 es que tanto zoom le queres dar al punto y coordenadas el par lat,long
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate= CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordenadas, 15); 
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate); //Lleva la camara a la latitud y longitud especificada
```